# multi column conditional count while aggregating values on time columns ( python's dataframes ) and percentages over the total of occurences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Well this is a tricky one, i will explain it directly with an example

Let's say we have this dataframe

```
ID Week  Alarm1   Alarm2
0   1    false    false
1   1     true    false
2   1    false    true
4   2    false    false
5   2     true    true
6   2    false    true
7   2    false    true
8   3     true    true
9   3     true    true
```

And now I want to aggregate them by week, keeping the columns alarm1 and alarm2 and counting those that were true:

```
Week Alarm1 Alarm2
 1     1      1
 2     1      3
 3     2      2
```

Tried some stuff like: `data.groupby(["week","Alarm1","Alarm2"]).size()` but as expected i only get a table with all the possible false/true options)

**Bonus extra question**: And what if now I want the %? Week 3 had less total rows so I want those alarm to weigtht more. I would love to divide on the fly each value by the total number of rows of each wek to get something like this:

```
Week Alarm1 Alarm2
 1    0.33   0.33
 2    0.25   0.75
 3     1       1
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first part:** (if ID is not a column ignore the drop and proceed with the rest of the code)

```
>>df.drop('ID',axis=1).replace({True:1, False:0}).groupby('Week').sum().reset_index()
    Week    Alarm1  Alarm2
0   1       1       1
1   2       1       3
2   3       2       2
```

**For the second part:**

```
df.groupby('Week')['Alarm1','Alarm2'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()/x.count()).reset_index()

    Week    Alarm1  Alarm2
0   1   0.333333    0.333333
1   2   0.250000    0.750000
2   3   1.000000    1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
data.groupby('Week').sum()
```

To obtain the number of true values (remember that True=1, False=0).

To obtain the percentage, just do:

```
data.groupby('week').sum()/data.groupby('week').count()
```

Comment: Thank you! Althougth i checked another answer because it was more specific to my case, i used yout little trick for the second part of the problem as instead of alarm1, alarm2...  have a ton of columns at it was super fast to do it with the matrix division :)

Comment: @LoïcV glad it helped. Would you consider upvoting the answer?